# mpdf after break page next page header text should be change

Tags: php, mpdf

hello please check pdf sample,
I'm using mpdf to generate a pdf document in php.

I got [this pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/18vwc81oj5zhp2l/mpdf.pdf?dl=0) generated by the code below.

1st copy is perfect, but second copy of 1st page top header title show wrong  i want to 2nd copy on header `$title2`

Can you help me?

```
<?php
include('mPDF/mpdf.php');
$mpdf = new mPDF('c', 'A4', '9', '', '10', '18', '55', '50', '50', '12', 'P');
$html = '

    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>';

for ($i = 1; $i < 80; $i++) {
    $html .= '<div>Here is the text of the first chapter</div>';
}
$html .= '</body>
    </html>';

$title1 = "<p style='text-align:right; margin:0px; font-size:15px;'>ORIGINAL </p>";
$title2 = "<p style='text-align:right; margin:0px; font-size:15px;'>DUPLICATE</p>";
$title3 = "<p style='text-align:right; margin:0px; font-size:15px;'>TRIPLICATE</p>";


$mpdf->SetHeader($title1 . $header);
$mpdf->SetFooter($footer . 'Page No. {PAGENO} of {nbpg}');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->SetFooter($footer . 'Page No. {PAGENO} of {nbpg}');

$mpdf->WriteHTML('<pagebreak resetpagenum="1" pagenumstyle="1" suppress="" />');

$mpdf->SetHeader($title2 . $header);
$mpdf->SetFooter($footer . 'Page No. {PAGENO} of {nbpg}');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->SetFooter($footer . 'Page No. {PAGENO} of {nbpg}');
$mpdf->Output();
```

[PDF Sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/18vwc81oj5zhp2l/mpdf.pdf?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/setheader.html) the `SetHeader` function can take three parameters, the third of which is $write.

This third parameter forces the Header to be written immediately to the current page. Use it if the header is being set after the new page has been added.

Change to:

```
$mpdf->SetHeader($title2 . $header, [], true);
```

and it should allow the second header to be seen.

You may also want to look at [AddPage()](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/addpage.html).

Comment: Thank You so much Jason. this code very helpful for me